# Calibrating Kinect with surroundings

Tags: ros, kinect, robot-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone <br >

I am having a serious problem with my Kinect project, but since many are working with the Kinect camera, then I hope someone have solved this or atleast have an idea how to solve it. <br >

My Kinect camera is able to find a suitable grasping point, but is done according to the optical frame of the Kinect camera. In order to use it with a robot arm, then I need to know how the base of the robot arm is located according to the camera. <br >

I have tried to use markers on the robots end-effector and combine it with the knowledge of the forward kinematic, but apparently there is some serious errors with the markers (ArToolKitPlus), which means the distance on the z-axis is several centimeters off. In am not entirely sure why, but atleast I am looking for an alternative method to calibrate the Kinect camera with the environment and I hope someone have some ideas <br >

Regards <br >
Sebastian Aslund

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10002/calibrating-kinect-with-surroundings/) by [Aslund](https://answers.ros.org/users/163/aslund/) on ROS Answers with karma: 289 on 2011-05-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to check out a submission to the ROS 3D contest: Automatic Calibration of the 3D pose of the Kinect with respect to the robot base. Uses fast ICP to track the 3D pose of the Kinect, then uses a global optimization to retrieve the static transformation. (http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/Automatic%20Calibration%20of%20Extrinsic%20Parameters)

This should help you get an initial guess between your base link and kinect. So that you can start making a URDF.

Then you might want to look at this tutorial: How to learn kinematic models of articulated objects only by using a webcam and a laptop. (http://www.ros.org/wiki/articulation_tutorials/Tutorials/ArticulationWebcamDemo)

Which might help you finish making your URDF.

Another approach might be to use the ar_pose package to determine the rough locations of each joint in the camera frame and then use those measurements to construct a URDF.

Unfortunately people typically get out a ruler and just measure these things because it is faster and in general more accurate.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-06-27**:
You might look at ar_kinect instead of ar_pose, as it is far more accurate on the Kinect, and requires no calibration of camera parameters.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try making a URDF model and joint-publisher for your robot arm - the tf library will then take care of whatever transformations you need.

[URDF tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials)

---

Originally posted by [rbtying](https://answers.ros.org/users/285/rbtying/) with karma: 73 on 2011-05-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To expand on rbtying's answer:

In ROS, transformations between different coordinate frames, such as the optical frame of the Kinect and the base of the robot arm are handled by the [tf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf) library. You just have to specify the transform between those two frames and then can use the tf library to compute the transformations between different frames.

Long answer:

First create an URDF file of your arm, upload it to the parameter server (param name "robot_description"), have some node publishing the joint_states of the current arm configuration and run the [robot_state_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_state_publisher) to integrate URDF and joint states into [tf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf) messages. Now you should be able to visualize your arm state in RViz.

Next, you have to specify the relative position of your Kinect to the arm. Assuming that this is a fixed transform, you can use the [static_transform_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#static_transform_publisher). For example, let's take a look at `kinect_camera/launch/kinect_with_tf.launch`:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="world_to_kinect_rgb" 
    args="0 0 1.10 -1.57 0 -1.57 /world /kinect_rgb 10" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_rgb_to_kinect_depth" 
    args="-0.03 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /kinect_rgb /kinect_depth 10" />

  <include file="$(find kinect_camera)/launch/kinect_node.launch" />
</launch>
```

The first node specification gives the transform between the `/world` frame and the `/kinect_rgb` frame. Here, you have to replace `/world` by the base link of your robot arm, let's say `/arm_base_link`, if that is the name given in your URDF model. To find the correct parameters for that transform, you can use the [tf_publisher_gui](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf_publisher_gui) instead of the static_transform_publisher. Now you should be able to visualize both your robot model and the Kinect point cloud together in RViz. Fiddle around with the parameters to get your robot model lined up with the actual arm visible in the point cloud.

Now, whenever you have a point in the optical frame of the Kinect, you can use tf to just transform that point into the base frame of the robot arm.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-05-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I'm not personally familiar with this package and I don't know how applicable/reusable it might be on your problem, but it might be a good starting point: [pr2_calibration](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_calibration).

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-05-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1